# What is the correct definition of a trapezium?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

There are two different definitions of trapezium in two different textbooks or resources .
Some say that :-

> Trapezium is a quadrilateral with ***atleast*** one pair of opposite sides parallel .

And the second definition is :-

> Trapezium is a quadrilateral with ***exact*** one pair of opposite sides parallel.

Can someone tell which out of the following definition is correct?

[Second definition](https://byjus.com/maths/trapezium/)

OR

[First definition](https://www.embibe.com/exams/trapezium/)

Comment: Definitions are neither "correct" nor "incorrect".  They simply tell you what a word is meant to mean in the context of whatever you are reading.  However, the more *common* definition is probably "a trapezoid is a quadrilateral with *exactly* one pair of parallel sides.

Comment: If we have two pairs of parallel sides , we still have a trapezoid , just a more special one, namely a parallelogram. It is not wrong to consider a parallelogram to be a trapezoid , although we usually choose the best name to characterize it.

Comment: Trapezoid has two parallel sides and  extension of two other sides meet at a point.

Comment: It's worth noting that mathematicians can't even agree on [whether zero is a natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). *Trapezium* happens to be another context-sensitive term. (The fact that the US uses *trapezoid* adds to the fun and/or confusion.) A thoughtful author will explain the preferred usage in a work. Wikipedia's ["Trapezoid" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid#Inclusive_vs_exclusive_definition) has a discussion of the "inclusive" vs "exclusive" definitions of the term. This has also been discussed a few times here on Math.SE; try a site search.